# Hapi.js Content Negotiation

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-negotiation, hapi.js

I want to do content negotiation in my hapi routes to I can return the type of data my client can accept.

With express I would do somthing like this

```
res.format({
  "text/plain": function(){
    res.send("Text Response");
  },

  "text/html": function(){
    res.send("HTML Response");
  },

  "application/json": function(){
    res.json({ message: "JSON Response" });
  },

  "default": function() {
    // log the request and respond with 406
    res.status(406).send("Not Acceptable");
  }
});
```

Is there a built in way to do this with hapi? I looked through the [API docs](http://hapijs.com/api) and didn't see anything. Am I stuck rolling my own solution?

Comment: hope that answers your question, https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/252

Comment: Thanks. I guess I will have to roll my own.

Answer (score 1):

As @ubaltaci pointed, there is not built in way.

However there is a *hapi* plugin in development [hapi-negotiator](https://github.com/felipeleusin/hapi-negotiator) build on top of module [Negotiator](https://github.com/jshttp/negotiator).

Haven't time to try it yet, but will do soon. (I'll update my answer then)